# "npm install react react-dom --save-dev", there is no introduced dependency package in the "package.json" file~

Tags: npm

[npm Execution error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dKX9.png)

[There is no import dependency package, such as: {react, react-dom}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icAUd.png)

ths very much~

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer is my node before the installation is not uninstalled (uninstall), making the installation is always wrong, before trying a lot of ways are invalid, I re-uninstall the software, re-installed, and now all modules are Ok, Thanks in advance~